# AJAX Call Is Not Working With The Controller Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

Salaamun Alekum

My AJAX Call Is Not Calling The Controller Action In ASP.NET MVC Web Applicaiton Project

Bellow Is My AJAX Call In Javascript And Next Is Controller's Action

AJAX Call

```
    var requestUrl = '/Home/GetCurrentUser';
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(data)
        {
            debugger;
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error)
        {
            debugger;
            alert(error);
        }
```

The Controller Action

```
[SharePointContextFilter]
        public JsonResult GetCurrentUser()
        {
            CurrentUserModel um = new CurrentUserModel();
            try
            {
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.User spUser = null;
                var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);
                using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
                {
                    if (clientContext != null)
                    {
                        spUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;

                        clientContext.Load(spUser, user => user.Title, user => user.Email, user => user.LoginName);

                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                        um.Name = spUser.Title;
                        um.Email = spUser.Email;
                        um.LoginName = spUser.LoginName;
                    }
                }

                SharePointBoxOnline.Common.User u = UserManager.Instance.GetUserByEmail(um.Email);

                if (u != null)
                {
                    um.ClientId = u.FK_Client_ID;
                    um.UserId = u.User_ID;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                SharePointBoxOnlineAppWeb.Classes.LogsManager.LogException(e.Message, e.StackTrace, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString(), "Added logging functionality to store the exception information in the Database", DateTime.Now);
            }

            return Json(um, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Errors Results In AJAX Are

error.description

> Invalid character

status

> parsererror

xhr.responseText

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Error</title>
    <link href="/Content/css?v=MDbdFKJHBa_ctS5x4He1bMV0_RjRq8jpcIAvPpKiN6U1" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>An unexpected error has occurred.</h2>
            <p>Please try again by launching the app installed on your site.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Internet Explorer","requestId":"673b269bf2c74e39a9496d69f3e0b62e"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:14069/4b2e31c8e2cf413facce9558ed0cb3ff/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Thank You Stackoverflow And Members Of Stackoverflow Please Let Me Know If You Require Further Details

Thank You

Comment: What is not working? Are you hitting the controller method. What errors are showing in the browser console?

Comment: What character encoding do you have sent from the backend?

Comment: Salaam @William Thank You For Helping
I Presume You Are Asking About ' "application/json" ' I Want To Receive JSON As Data
Thank You

Comment: In the Ajax request you set content-type, but that is referring to the body you send in the request. The accept header is to tell the server what content should be sent back. But I was more thinking about if there was some weird chat encoding like UTF-16

Comment: Thank You For Clarifying [Smile] @William No I Am Not Encoding Anything Like Such I Am Sorry For Misunderstanding 

Thank You

Comment: Your response text shows that your throwing an error on the server. You need to debug your code. And you can remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` - your not sending any data to the server. Start by commenting out all the code inside the method (and the `[SharePointContextFilter]`) and just add `return Json("it works", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` then start gradually uncommenting code to find where the error is.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
    url: requestUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data)
    {
        debugger;
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error)
    {
        debugger;
        alert(error);
    }
});
```